# Scala: correct shell command doesn't work using ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala, ssh, sshpass

I'm trying to run a command inside Scala, this command is a ssh call that require the execution of a cmd line inside the serve machine, it looks like

```
sshpass -p PSW ssh USER@IP "/absolute_path/program -input /absolute_path/filename"
```

if I print this string from Scala and run it directly inside the shell it works correctly, but running it using

```
cmd !
```

the SERVER returns an error

```
bash: /absolute_path/program -input /absolute_path/filename: No such file or directory
```

someone can tell me how fix please? thank you

UPDATED

```
var nestedcmd = "/absolute_path/program" +
  " -input "+ server_dir +"/"+ filename

var cmd = "sshpass -p "+ server_pass +
  " ssh "+ server_user +"@"+ server_ip +
  " \""+ nestedcmd + "\""

println(cmd)  
cmd !
```

println produces the query that I'm trying to run directly inside the shell, cmd ! should run the same command

I'm using this solution during the development, because in production the code will be run directly into the server and I will not need ssh call, but for development I need to run the "program" on the server from my pc

SOLVED

It was sufficient remove the quotes, ssh takes what comes after the connection parameters as commands to run on the server

Comment: Did you try wrapping the whole thing with  """ (triple quotes) it will pass the command as is

Comment: I just tried, is the same, runs correctly copying the string into shell but not directly from Scala

Comment: can you post more code? it seems like shell is reading an EOL before the input line or whatever and looks at the path as a separate command

Comment: also can you give more context on "cmd !"? are you using sbt? and if not why not? also did you try running the command in REPL?

Comment: I'm not using repl or sbt, i will update the question with more code

Answer (score 0):

Using formatted strings can help with such problems

```
var nestedcmd = """/absolute_path/program -input $server_dir/filename"""

var cmd = """sshpass -p $server_pass ssh $server_user@$server_ip \$nestedcmd"""
```